# emacs 文字コード変換 C-x RET f で、Shift-JISがリストにない

Tags: emacs

emacsでの文字コード変換に使う、
C-x RET f （set-buffer-file-coding-system）
を使ってShift-JISに変換しようとしたのですが、
Shift-JISのみ変換候補のリストに存在せず、no matchとなってしまいます。
これはどのような現象なのでしょうか？

以下、環境を記載します。
Emacs V.24.5(9.0)  （Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite上）
homebrewからインストールし、日本語インラインパッチがあたっています。

Answer (score 3):

"shift_jis" (ハイフンでは無くアンダースコア) であれば候補にあるはずです。

Comment: `japanese-shift-jis` あるいは単に `sjis` でもいけますね。

Answer (score 3):

C-x RET f をした後、TABやC-iを押すと、候補が表示されると思います。
そこから検索したりして適当なものを選択するとよいと思います。

Windowsの文字コードに合わせたい、というのであれば
japanese-cp932-dos
にするのがよいと思います。
Windows-31Jで改行コードがCRLFになります。
㈱や①といった文字を扱うことができます。

cp932-dosというのもありますが、何が違うのかはよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: ちなみに`cp932`は`define-coding-system-alias`により設定された`japanese-cp932`の別名です

Comment: @emasaka さん、ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。